# Ad-hoc provisioning profile not attaching with Archive build on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I intend to upload my app on TestFlight. I am manually signing the build on **Xcode 8** simply by importing the provisioning profiles that I generated from Apple Developer Console. The right Signing Certificates and Teams are immediately attached, and I am making sure that I am importing the **Ad-hoc** distribution provisioning profile on the **Signing (Release)** section.

I have read that TestFlight builds must have the Ad-hoc profile and not the actual Distribution profile attached. Anyways, when I proceed to archive my app, the provisioning profile that shows to be attached is the **XC: my bundle ID** profile that seems to be automatically built on Apple Developer Console **everytime**.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: You might not be doing anything wrong. Have you tried uploading the app? It might work...

Comment: The thing is my provisioning profile does not share the same name that I see attached with the Archive. My provisioning profile is called say, `Ad-hoc Test` while the attached one is called `XC: my_bundle_id`.

Are you saying that the `XC:` might be pointing towards the Ad-hoc?

Comment: I'm saying that if you are not having any problem yet, you should not be getting your knickers in a twist. Go ahead and try to upload the build! If there's a problem, don't worry, Xcode will tell you, and _then_ you can deal with the issue.

Comment: Ok so like you said I've tried to not get my knickers in a twist and tried it anyway. Unfortunately this build will not work as my push notifications have not come in. I am certain that pushes work because I've tested them, but not on TestFlight. Any suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: But that's a totally different question. If you have a different question, ask a new question. Meanwhile, it sounds like uploading to the app store worked fine (i.e. you were able to upload and play the role of a test flight tester), so please delete _this_ question.

Comment: I'm saying the reason the pushes are not working is because of the wrong provisioning profile, ergo the one that is not the Ad-hoc. Which is why I asked this question since X code is attaching the wrong. I think my title  question remains valid. Also the question I poised was not "why isn't my app building on Test flight"

Comment: Okay, well, if you want to take total control of what provisioning profile is used, uncheck the automatic provisioning box and go right ahead. Let's see what happens then.

Comment: That is exactly what I did, which is how I manually imported them into Xcode in the first place. I also checked my Code Signing properties and they're all pointing to the correct certificates and profiles including (Ad-hoc)